# QTP: Data Driven: For loop

Tags: automation, qtp, hp-uft

Aim: Login to the sample flight application with multiple users

Excel File:

**agentName           Password**
user1                    mercury
user2                    mercury
user3                    mercury
user4                    mercury

QTP Code:

```
datatable.Import "D:\QTP\TestData\login credentials.xls"
Dim i
Dim iRow
iRow = datatable.GetRowCount

For i = 1 to iRow

systemutil.Run "C:\Program Files\HP\QuickTest Professional\samples\flight\app\flight4a.exe"

Dialog("Login").WinEdit("Agent Name:").Set datatable.Value("agentName")
Dialog("Login").WinEdit("Password:").Set datatable.Value("Password")
Dialog("Login").WinButton("OK").Click

systemutil.CloseProcessByName"flight4a.exe"

datatable.SetNextRow

Next
```

QTP runs the script 16 times.
The value of 'i' range from 1-4 and then is set back to 1. Why?
Pointer should leave the for loop ideally.
Can you please explain the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is probably set to "Run on all rows" which means it will run the script once for each row in the global data table.  When executing, you are also looping through each row of the data table, so what you're doing is this...

```
Iteration 1
  Loop 1
  Loop 2
  Loop 3
  Loop 4
Iteration 2
  Loop 1
  Loop 2
  Loop 3
  Loop 4
Iteration 3
  Loop 1
  Loop 2
  Loop 3
  Loop 4
Iteration 4
  Loop 1
  Loop 2
  Loop 3
  Loop 4
```

That should be why you are seeing the script execute 16 times (4 x 4 = 16).  Either set your script to run one iteration only or stop your script from internally looping the data table.